# Can't call "on" to bind methods

Tags: events, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I cant register any events with the "on" Mehotd.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

`Ext.define('faragoo.view.Main', {`

```
extend: 'Ext.Container',
alias: 'widget.stream',
xtype: 'stream',
id : 'stream',   
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.form.Panel'
],

initialize: function () {

   this.on('afterrender', function() { alert('rendered'); } );

}
```

}

And this simple example doesnt work also :

`Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', function() { console.log("orientationchange"); }, this, {buffer: 50 });`

Same Error :-(

Comment: Seems correct to me. Did you try the second example in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/events) explains how to properly add events to a component.

Bind the event after the component is created:

```
var myButton = Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click me'
});

myButton.on('tap', function() {
    alert("Event listener attached by .on");
});
```

Or bind an event with using a listener config:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'My Button',
    listeners: {
        tap: function() {
            alert("You tapped me");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if OP calls `callParent()` in his function, Yes indeed.

Comment: That's what I thought as first as well, but I tried without calling callParent() and it still worked. But still his second example should work anyways.